using attrs pre-commit mypy error: Unexpected keyword argument
mypy runs perfectly on terminal, but when running on pre-commit stage, I am getting the error Unexpected keyword argument for every property in my class
from attrs import define, field
@define(
    frozen=True,
    kw_only=True,
    slots=True,
    auto_detect=True,
    order=False,
    auto_attribs=True,
)
class MyClass:
   a: str = field(default="")
   b: str = field(default="")

   def myMethod(self) -> Any:
     return MyClass(a=self.a, b="b_value") 

mypy pre-commit failed:
error: Unexpected keyword argument "a" for MyClass (line: return MyClass...)
error: Unexpected keyword argument "b" for MyClass (line: return MyClass...)
.pre-commit-config.yaml:
 - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: v1.11.2
    hooks:
      - id: mypy
        args: ["--config-file", "mypy.ini"]


Can you add the definition of MyClass?

Yes, I can. Done

mypy needs a plugin to understand how define modifies the decorated class. Is that installed on the other machine?

I tried with plugins=mypy.plugins.attrs [mypy.ini] and got this error: Plugin "mypy.plugins.attrs" does not define entry point function "plugin"  [misc]. attrs documentation mentions a custom plugin here https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/extending.html (the weird thing is that errors only are happening with pre-commit, when I run mypy on terminal everything is ok)

Python pre-commit hooks run in their own individual virtualenv, not your project's virtualenv. So they don't have access to your project pip dependencies. You can run it from pre-commit in a way that works, but you have to configure the hook as repo: local, language: system i.e. run mypy as a local shell command (with your virtualenv activated).

alternatively, as the README states:

Because pre-commit runs mypy from an isolated virtualenv (without your dependencies) you may also find it useful to add the typed dependencies to additional_dependencies so mypy can better perform dynamic analysis

ala:
 - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: v1.11.2
    hooks:
      - id: mypy
        additional_dependencies: [attrs]
        # also you don't need this, mypy checks mypy.ini by default
        # args: ["--config-file", "mypy.ini"]


disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Thank you so much; this is what I was looking for

Don't use Mypy from pre-commit. Mypy requires to see the 3rd party packages the code using, even though it has an attrs plugin built-in that requires no activation.
You can test it very easily (and I just did): install Mypy into your venv with your project and attrs and run it from there: it passes.

Yes, that's what I am doing, not triggering mypy at pre-commit. Thank you

Just in case, I have created a bug https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/17735

agree with hynek, see also my writeup here https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/13916
